# How to determine which gems ship bundled with versions of Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Which gems, and their specific versions, ship bundled with various versions of Ruby on Linux?

How can I this information without having to install each version of Ruby and running `gem list`? Are there manifest files for this online anywhere?

Comment: You probably need Bundler. From the official website "Bundler provides a consistent environment for Ruby projects by tracking and installing the exact gems and versions that are needed" https://bundler.io/

Comment: You need to install bundler `gem install bundler`, create a `Gemfile` file and put into the gems that you application requires, i.e. `gem 'sinatra'`. Finally, run in your terminal `bundle install` from your project folder and Bundler will download and generate a `Gemfile.lock`with all the declared gems, its gem dependencies and respective versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which gems, and their specific versions, ship bundled with various versions of Ruby on Linux?

This actually does not depend so much on the Ruby version but on the Ruby implementation. For example, in Rubinius, the compiler, the parser, the Abstract Syntax Tree, the Instruction Set, and the standard library are all separate gems.

Whereas in YARV, the parser and the compiler are just parts of the monolithic VM, and the standard library is just part of the source tree.

> How can I this information without having to install each version of Ruby and running `gem list`? Are there manifest files for this online anywhere?

Again, this depends heavily on the implementation.

For [TruffleRuby](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby), you can find the list of *bundled gems* and *default gems* in the file [`versions.json`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/versions.json), which currently looks like this:

```
{
  "ruby": {
    "version": "2.6.5",
    "revision": 67812
  },

  "gems": {
    "default": {
      "bundler": "1.17.2",
      "gem": "3.0.3",
      "irb": "1.0.0",
      "rake": "12.3.2",
      "rdoc": "6.1.2"
    },

    "bundled": {
      "did_you_mean": "1.3.0",
      "minitest": "5.11.3",
      "net-telnet": "0.2.0",
      "power_assert": "1.1.3",
      "rake": "12.3.2",
      "test-unit": "3.2.9",
      "xmlrpc": "0.3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

For [YARV](http://atdot.net/yarv/), you can find the list of *bundled gems* in the file [`gems/bundled_gems`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/gems/bundled_gems) in the YARV source code, which currently looks like this:

```
minitest 5.14.0 https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest
power_assert 1.2.0 https://github.com/ruby/power_assert
rake 13.0.1 https://github.com/ruby/rake
test-unit 3.3.5 https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit
rexml 3.2.4 https://github.com/ruby/rexml
rss 0.2.9 https://github.com/ruby/rss
```

I am not very familiar with the [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/) build system, so I was not able to find a simple single location for the list of gems. I found a couple, but I don't think the list is exhaustive:

[`gems_list.txt`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/gems_list.txt) in the [main Rubinius repository](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/):

```
bundler-1.16.1.gem
minitest-5.11.1.gem
racc-1.4.14.gem
rake-12.3.0.gem
rb-readline-0.5.5.gem
rdoc-5.1.0.gem
```

The [Rubinius Code](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code) repository contains tools to compile and run code on the Rubinius platform, which are used in the Rubinius Ruby implementation. The repository contains the following gems:

- [`rubinius-ast.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-ast.gemspec): `rubinius-ast` – *An Abstract Syntax Tree for the Rubinius language platform.*
- [`rubinius-compiler.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-compiler.gemspec): `rubinius-compiler` – *A Bytecode compiler for the Rubinius language platform.*
- [`rubinius-instructions.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-instructions.gemspec): `rubinius-instructions` – *Support tools for Rubinius instruction set.*
- [`rubinius-melbourne.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-melbourne.gemspec): `rubinius-melbourne` – *Ruby parser extracted from MRI.*
- [`rubinius-processor.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-processor.gemspec): `rubinius-processor` – *Converts Melbourne parse tree into an AST.*
- [`rubinius-toolset.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-toolset.gemspec): `rubinius-toolset` – *A registry for Rubinius code tools.*
- [`rubinius-code.gemspec`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius-code/blob/master/rubinius-code.gemspec): `rubinius-code` – *A suite of tools for working with code on the Rubinius language platform.* (A meta-gem depending on the other 6 gems, `rubinius-ast`, `rubinius-compiler`, `rubinius-instructions`, `rubinius-melbourne`, `rubinius-processor`, and `rubinius-toolset`.)

Of course, in addition to all of this, the `ruby` package of any Linux distribution may, at the discretion of the maintainer of that package, depend on, or install any number of gems as well.

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted - not only is the answer correct, but it left me more educated than when I first asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for `gem list --local` to see which gems have been installed for a particular project.

Ruby is a language like Python, PERL or C#, but a gem is a Ruby library, just a Ruby script that serves some purpose, like any other language has libraries to handle things like Time objects or perhaps making an HTTP request.

Saying "which gems come with a version of Ruby" is a strange request to me, because, specifically on Linux, if you were to compile Ruby from source, you wouldn't have any gems.  You would have installed only the interpreter on your machine.  Gems are things that you would have to install once you had a specific version of Ruby.

There may be some auto-installer Linux packages that automatically install a version of Ruby with commonly-used gems.  MOST methods to install Ruby will include functionality - as TinMan pointed out in the comments - like rubygems - to get you started.

On macOS:

```
ls -ltra ~/.rbenv/versions
Apr 27 12:13 2.4.5
Aug 21  2019 2.4.6
Mar  5 06:35 2.5.0
Jan 12 20:57 2.5.3
Oct  4  2019 2.6.3
Feb 11 09:32 2.6.5
Mar  4 22:20 2.7.0
```

Those are the Ruby versions I installed, and inside each is a folder of gems I installed for each version:

```
ls -l .rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems
```

```
actioncable-5.0.7.2  benchmark-ips-2.7.2  excon-0.71.1  io-like-0.3.0  parser-2.7.0.4  recaptcha-5.2.1  sidekiq-6.0.7
actioncable-5.2.4.1  better_errors-2.5.1  execjs-2.7.0  io-like-0.3.1  pg-0.21.0       recaptcha-5.3.0  signet-0.12.0
```

There are many more gems for that particular version.

Just list the files in the directory of the installed version of Ruby and you'll find everything.

Comment: So I installed the ruby rpm on Fedora and the gems which come with it include `rdoc`, `bigdecimal`, `io-console`, etc... I didn't realize that this is actually due to the Fedora package manager, and not Ruby itself. Does that make sense? I thought that these gems were part of RUBY but actually, they are part of the rpm that Ruby is bundled with. But for example, in C, C is ALWAYS shipped with <stdio.h> by default, so it "comes with" C. Sorry for the confusion and I appreciate the explanation :)

Comment: @the_endian rdoc and bigdecimal etc are part of the [standard library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/). These are shipped with core Ruby, but you have to explicitly `require` them before use.

Comment: @steenslag when I do a `gem list`, those show up as gems with their separate version numbers. Does the standard lib have different version of gems included with it or are they considered part of the ruby release itself?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what the core and standard libraries are, versus gems. The core and standard are similar to the normal included files that you'd use with C. Gems are equivalent to include files you'd grab from other sites, other people. The libraries are bundled with Ruby and we don't control them as they're part of the distribution. Gems _usually_ are distributed elsewhere. That said, the standard Ruby distribution does include a few gems, like `rubygems` itself, which lets you get other gems using the `gem` command.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not misunderstanding anything, @steenslag said that `rdoc` and `bigdecimal` are "part of the standard library." I'm saying that when I enter `gem list`, those two gems are listed. Therefore, according to `gem` itself, they are `gems`.

Comment: @theTinMan: There is currently work underway, and has been for quite a while, to gemify large parts of the standard library. For this, the notion of *bundled gems* has been introduced, which are gems that are bundled as part of the Ruby distribution to form (parts of) the standard library, but can be updated separately without having to update the whole Ruby distribution.

Comment: "Saying "which gems come with a version of Ruby" is a strange request to me, because, specifically on Linux, if you were to compile Ruby from source, you wouldn't have any gems." – Huh? Of course you would. You would get the bundled gems which make up the standard library, which is *exactly* what the OP is asking about.